# SKAction.repeatActionForever only calculates random number on first call

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I want to make it so my column generates a new y value overtime it is teleported so that it always moves at a different height. For some reason, the random number call is only called the first time and from then on the action uses that same number instead of calling a new one. Here is my code:

```
let slideAction2A = SKAction.moveByX(-colTravel, y: 0, duration: 5)
let teleportAction2A = SKAction.moveToX(colInitialPosCGFloat, duration: 0)
let newLocation = SKAction.moveToY(getFloat(), duration: 0)
let teleportActionGroup2A = SKAction.group([teleportAction2A,newLocation])
let col2ASequence = SKAction.sequence([slideAction2A,teleportActionGroup2A])
let runCol2A = SKAction.repeatActionForever(col2ASequence)
let col2ADelaySlide = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 0, duration: 2.5)
let delayAndRun2A = SKAction.sequence([col2ADelaySlide,runCol2A])
column2A.runAction(delayAndRun2A)


func getFloat() -> CGFloat {
    var x: CGFloat
    x = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(200))
    x += CGFloat(newScreenHeight)
    print(x)
    return x
}
```

full code here:

```

```
//
//  GameScene.swift
//
//

import SpriteKit
import CoreMotion

class GameScene: SKScene {
    let world = SKNode()
    let house = Player()
    let ground = Ground()
    var screenCenterY = CGFloat()
    let initialPlayerPosition = CGPoint(x: 150, y: 250)
    var playerProgress = CGFloat()
    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    var destX:CGFloat = 0.0
    var destY:CGFloat = 0.0
    var test = SKNode()
    let newScreenHeight: Int = 0
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    var screenHeight : CGFloat = 0

    let colWidInt:Int = 0
    let colWidCG:CGFloat = 0
    let houseWid = 0
    //let newScreenHeight:Int = 0
    let colInitialPosInt:Int  = 0
    let colInitialPosCGFloat:CGFloat = 0
    let colTravel:CGFloat = 0

    var column2A = SKSpriteNode()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        print("yao 1")
        // Set a sky-blue background color:
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.4, green: 0.6, blue: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)

        // Add the world node as a child of the scene:
        self.addChild(world)

        // Store the vertical center of the screen:
        screenCenterY = self.size.height / 2
        house.spawn(world, position: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))


        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        screenHeight = screenSize.height
        //screenWidthInt = Int(screenWidth)

        let colWidInt = 50
        let colWidCG:CGFloat = CGFloat(colWidInt)
        let houseWid = 50
        let newScreenHeight:Int = Int(screenHeight)
        let colInitialPosInt:Int  = Int(screenWidth)+colWidInt/2
        let colInitialPosCGFloat:CGFloat = CGFloat(colInitialPosInt)
        let colTravel:CGFloat = CGFloat(colInitialPosInt+colWidInt/2)

        // A bronze coin:

        let column1A = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.greenColor(), size: CGSize(width: colWidCG, height: screenHeight))
        column1A.position = CGPoint(x: colInitialPosInt, y: newScreenHeight+35)
        self.addChild(column1A)



        let column1B = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.greenColor(), size: CGSize(width: colWidCG, height: screenHeight))
        column1B.position = CGPoint(x: colInitialPosInt, y: -35)
        self.addChild(column1B)

        column2A = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: colWidCG, height: screenHeight))
        column2A.position = CGPoint(x: colInitialPosInt, y: newScreenHeight+35)
        self.addChild(column2A)

        let column2B = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.greenColor(), size: CGSize(width: colWidCG, height: screenHeight))
        column2B.position = CGPoint(x: colInitialPosInt, y: -35)
        self.addChild(column2B)

        let slideAction1A = SKAction.moveByX(-colTravel, y: 0, duration: 5)
        let teleportAction1A = SKAction.moveToX(colInitialPosCGFloat, duration: 0)
        let col1ASequence = SKAction.sequence([slideAction1A,teleportAction1A])
        let runCol1A = SKAction.repeatActionForever(col1ASequence)
        column1A.runAction(runCol1A)

        let slideAction1B = SKAction.moveByX(-colTravel, y: 0, duration: 5)
        let teleportAction1B = SKAction.moveToX(colInitialPosCGFloat, duration: 0)
        let col1BSequence = SKAction.sequence([slideAction1B,teleportAction1B])
        let runCol1B = SKAction.repeatActionForever(col1BSequence)
        column1B.runAction(runCol1B)

        let slideAction2A = SKAction.moveByX(-colTravel, y: 0, duration: 5)
        let teleportAction2A = SKAction.moveToX(colInitialPosCGFloat, duration: 0)
        let newLocation = SKAction.moveToY(getFloat(), duration: 0)
        let teleportActionGroup2A = SKAction.group([teleportAction2A,newLocation])
        let col2ASequence = SKAction.sequence([slideAction2A,teleportActionGroup2A])
        let runCol2A = SKAction.repeatActionForever(col2ASequence)
        let col2ADelaySlide = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 0, duration: 2.5)
        let delayAndRun2A = SKAction.sequence([col2ADelaySlide,runCol2A])
        column2A.runAction(delayAndRun2A)

        let slideAction2B = SKAction.moveByX(-colTravel, y: 0, duration: 5)
        let teleportAction2B = SKAction.moveToX(colInitialPosCGFloat, duration: 0)
        let col2BSequence = SKAction.sequence([slideAction2B,teleportAction2B])
        let runCol2B = SKAction.repeatActionForever(col2BSequence)
        let col2BDelaySlide = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 0, duration: 2.5)
        let delayAndRun2B = SKAction.sequence([col2BDelaySlide,runCol2B])
        column2B.runAction(delayAndRun2B)
        print("yao 4")


        self.motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
        if motionManager.accelerometerAvailable == true {
            // 2
            motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!, withHandler:{
                data, error in

                let currentX = self.house.position.x
                let currentY = self.house.position.y

                // 3
                if data!.acceleration.x < 0 {
                    self.destX = currentX + 2*CGFloat(data!.acceleration.x * 200)
                }

                else if data!.acceleration.x > 0 {
                    self.destX = currentX + 2*CGFloat(data!.acceleration.x * 200)
                }

                if data!.acceleration.y < 0 {
                    self.destY = currentY + CGFloat(data!.acceleration.y * 400)
                }

                else if data!.acceleration.y > 0 {
                    self.destY = currentY + CGFloat(data!.acceleration.y * 400)
                }

            })

        }

    }

    override func didSimulatePhysics() {

    }

    func getRand() -> CGFloat{
        var x: CGFloat
        x = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(200))
        //print("x is: ",x)
        //x += CGFloat(screenHeight)
        //print("ScreenHeight is : ",screenHeight)
        //print("new x is: ",x)
        return x
    }

    func getFloat() -> CGFloat {
        var x: CGFloat = getRand()
        //x = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(200))
        //print("x is: ",x)
        x += CGFloat(screenHeight)
        //print("ScreenHeight is : ",screenHeight)
        //print("new x is: ",x)
        return x
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    }

    override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    }

    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        let actionX = SKAction.moveToX(destX, duration: 0.3)
        let actionY = SKAction.moveToY(destY, duration: 0.3)
        let actionGroup = SKAction.group([actionX,actionY])
        house.runAction(actionGroup)


    }
}
```

```

Comment: That is how SKAction work. When action is created once, it is re-used later in your code, and its initial parameters can't be changed.  Instead you have to create a new action (most likely with a same key, to overwrite the previous action) ...

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35816237/3402095), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34633329/3402095) That is the logic you could use.

Comment: Hey Whirlwind. The difference between my code however is that the action I want to be recursive should not be run in the function call. I need to add it to another sequence etc. When I threw all that code into a function and called the function (just to test it), it did not execute in the same way that it did when it was outside the function. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: You should update your question with a workable (copy/pasteable) example... That way, it would be easier for everybody to debug / propose solutions... But if I came up with something useful, I will make my answer (but I am not really sure what you need).

Comment: Just to clarify : `col2ASequence` should move the column node to some location, then teleport it back on location with same x, but different y coordinate ? Also, about `col2ADelaySlide` variable.. Why did you named this variable like that, if it is not `SKAction.wait(...)` type of an action. There is no delay... ?

Comment: My goal is to replicate the flappy bird columns. As it is, the y radom number generator only works on the first iteration.  I didn't use SKAction.wait() because I didn't know that existed. The point of the col2ADelaySlide is to, on the very first time the code is ran, that it not slide for 2.5 seconds. This would give the first group of columns the chance to move halfway across the screen. The delay part works just as I intended but the new random number is where I am stuck. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, now is little bit clearer ... You should use SKAction.wait(duration) for a delay. It is meant for that... I will make my answer soon to show you one way of how you can generate obstacles...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is one way (and there are many ways) to the same thing.

What this code does is:

- create an obstacle
- move it from the left side, to the right side of the screen
- remove the obstacle when off-screen
- randomize obstacle's y coordinate on every obstacle creation

Just copy and paste to see how it works:

```
    import SpriteKit

    class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

       //MARK: - Sprite kit functionality
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        startSpawning()
    }

    func startSpawning(){

        let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(1.5)
        let block = SKAction.runBlock({[unowned self] in self.spawnObstacle()})
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, block])

        runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence), withKey: "spawning")
    }

    func spawnObstacle(){

        // 1) create an obstacle
        let obstacle = SKSpriteNode(color: .purpleColor(), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: frame.size.height/2.0))

        // 2) Place it outside the screen, next to the right edge and randomize the y position each time
        let lowerBound:CGFloat = -200   //Calcluate this to match your needs
        let upperBound:CGFloat = 200 //Calcluate this to match your needs
        let obstacleRandomY = randomBetweenNumbers(lowerBound, secondNum: upperBound)
        obstacle.position = CGPoint(x: frame.maxX + obstacle.size.width, y: obstacleRandomY)

        // 3) Add it to the scene
        addChild(obstacle)

        // 4) Move the obstacle from the right side, to the left side of a screen
        let move = SKAction.moveToX(-obstacle.calculateAccumulatedFrame().width, duration: 3)

        // 5) Remove the obstacle from the scene when off-screen
        let moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([move, SKAction.removeFromParent()])


        obstacle.runAction(moveAndRemove)
    }

    func randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: CGFloat, secondNum: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
        return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UINT32_MAX) * abs(firstNum - secondNum) + min(firstNum, secondNum)
    }

}
```

You can add another obstacle (upper pipe) and adjust a bit lowerBound and upperBound variables, so you will have an effect like in Flappy Birds...

Comment: Amazingly helpful! Thank you very much! My only question is how are there two columns being created in this code? It seems like there is only one being created. Thanks!

Comment: @lelephant  Yeah, I've made an example just for one obstacle. But you can use the same logic to create another one, right above to current one. You could even make a SKNode and add both, upper and lower obstacles, to the same container and then run moving action on that container. It is just about how you will define in which range you want to spawn those obstacles. That is up to you.

Comment: Hey Whirlwind! So I have been using your above example and it's worked beautifully. Now I wan't to also have the wait time decrease on each iteration. I tried a few different ways and it didn't work. Because you wrote this solution for me, could you check out my most recent question? Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616783/i-need-help-writing-a-swiftspritekit-function-which-will-run-a-wait-action-at-d

Comment: @lelephant Hey...I think this may help you (I got just briefly looked at your question because I am busy at the moment) http://stackoverflow.com/a/34633329/3402095. That answer explains how you can modify duration of an action. Actually, the real true is that you can't. What you can do, is to re-create the action, because, once created, the action (its duration parameter more precisely) can't be modified.

Comment: You're great! Thanks a lot!